# Is there a way to create pkg for python app on mac?

Tags: python, macos, pkg-file

I search around, still not sure if I can do it using python setup.py install  ...

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I want to package everything I made by python into a pkg or dog file, then this pkg file can be installed to other machines.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [`distutils` module](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/) to create a Python package. You can then use

```
python setup.py install
```

or

```
python setup.py build
```

to install/build the package.

Because Mac OS X is Unix-based, modules [will install/build just like on Unix](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#how-installation-works).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I'm quite new to these, could you please explain a little bit of this? How can I make pkg file by using python setup.py install  or build ?

Comment: I think the Python docs can do a better job than I. Here's [a quick tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html#distutils-simple-example) on creating your first setup script to package a module. Presumably, you already have your Python set up as a [Python package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)?